# Convergent Sequence of Analytic Functions, Do Their Derivatives Converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

If you have a sequence of real analytic functions that converge on every compact subset in your domain, do their derivatives necessarily converge to the derivatives of the function that they converge to?

Comment: $$f_n(x) = \frac{\sin (n^2x)}{n}$$ goes to zero uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$, is analytic, with analytic uniform limit. But the derivatives don't quite converge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the limit function, $F$, need not even be differentiable if the original sequence $\phi_n \rightarrow F$ pointwise. For an example on $[0,1]$, take $F = 1_{[1/2,1]}$ (indicator function) and mollify it with an approximation to the identity $\eta_n$. This yields a sequence $\phi_n = F \ast \eta_n$ such that $\phi_n \rightarrow F$. $\phi_n$ are analytic but $F$ is discontinuous.